# Make shorter code in javascript using if else conditions

Tags: javascript

I know about the ternary expression in javascript. However i don't know how to make this piece of code shorter.

```
if (x == false) {
    x = true;
    cancelAnimationFrame(BI.req);
}
else {
    x = false;
    BI.req = requestAnimationFrame(BI.fn.animate);
}
```

I guess I can make two separate functions and use them with the ternary expression. Something like this:

```
function cancel() {
    x = true;
    cancelAnimationFrame(BI.req);
}
function request() {
    x = false;
    BI.req = requestAnimationFrame(BI.fn.animate);
}

x == false ? cancel() : request();
```

But this doesn't feel like I am really making my code much shorter. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: I prefer your current code. It's not very repetitive at all. Maybe golfable, but only at the expensive of readability IMO

Comment: You need to understand that shorter code is necessarily better. *Readability* is  much more important than shorter code. Someone has to maintain your code at some point – it could even be you! And we've all been there where we wonder: what was the original coder thinking!?? Even when we were the one who wrote it a few months/years ago.

Comment: What is the practical reason for this "shortening"? Will you use these "cancel" and "request" functions somewhere else? If you do not just obscure the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ternary for the functions. And use `!` operator to set `x`

```
x ? BI.req = requestAnimationFrame(BI.fn.animate) : cancelAnimationFrame(BI.req)
x = !x
```

Or even more shorter

```
(x = !x) ? cancelAnimationFrame(BI.req) : BI.req = requestAnimationFrame(BI.fn.animate)
```

The question was about **shorter** code so I answered this. Otherwise your own snippet is fine or consider Nina Answers because these two lines are completely non-readable.

You shouldn't use ternary operator like that too. Don't use ternary operator instead of `if-else` whenever there are two or move expressions in any block.

Comment: Golf: `(x = !x) ? cancelAnimationFrame(BI.req) : BI.req = requestAnimationFrame(BI.fn.animate)` (no, not seriously proposing anyone actually write this into a code base :P )

Answer (score 4):

You could shorten it a bit by moving the assignment to the bottom and use a positive check.

```
if (x) {
    BI.req = requestAnimationFrame(BI.fn.animate);
} else {
    cancelAnimationFrame(BI.req);
}
x = !x;
```